# Does java classloader validate method body?

Tags: java, security, jvm

For Java compiler to resolve reference to another class in different file needs to be on classpath.

I know that if the class is not found on the classpath or the method signatures do not match some Exceptions are thrown.

However, is there any validation that compares compile time classpath with runtime classpath when it comes to method implementations?

What If I provide classpath with method signatures matching the ones during compile time but with different implementation.

Will there be no Validation error or any Exception thrown? That seems very insecure.

Comment: No; as long as the API doesn't change, you can swap an implementation at run-time. For example, upgrading log4j between minor releases does not require recompiling your application.

Comment: Well, they have to be in the same package, but yes you can replace them. You can see it as a feature. We've used it to replace buggy implementations before since classes are (or at least were in older versions of Java) loaded in order as specified on the classpath. It also supports upgrading of libraries.

Comment: That seems like a powerful thing but also very dangerous. You could change someones class file on the server and he would not notice it at all :D.

Comment: I think there's a way of `signing` and `sealing` Jar files to prevent corrupted or malicious code from being executed.  I can't help you with the details of how that works.  The basics are in the Java tutorials though.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/sealman.html  and https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/signindex.html

Comment: @markspace That was for applets; and they're essentially dead now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally speaking, no, as long as the signatures match some JVMs can even replace methods at runtime (modulo some additional constraints).

Of course a custom classloader implementation could perform extended validations, such as checking hashes/signatures.

What the JVM does [validate is the standards-conformance of the bytecode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10562901/1362755). I.e. bytecode cannot reference nonexistent stack slots, do arbitrary jumps or similar things that would lead to illegal behavior inside the JVM.